# Existe-t-il un nom en référence au participe passé "échu" ?

Tags: demande-de-mot, substantivation

Je me demande s'il est possible de reformuler une phrase de ce type :

> À terme échu, vous pourrez …

en quelque chose de comme ça :

> À ???? du terme, vous pourrez …

Ou *????* serait un nom, par exemple (je sais que ce mot n'existe pas, mais j'illustre mon propos), *échoiement*.

Existe-t-il un tel mot ?

Answer (score 9):

Je dirais simplement :

> À l'[échéance](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9ch%C3%A9ance) , ...